# Search filter and sort at the same time in an ASP.NET MVC table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem when searching by text and keeping the order at the same time. I can search for the text in the `DISTRITO` column and it lists the matches for that column, but when I sort it, the list returns to how it was at the beginning and the ordering is lost.

How could I keep both? That can filter by the `DISTRITO` column, and in that same table apply the order by the `PROMEDIOCAL` column?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ListarProfxServicio(int id,string CadenaBusqueda, string Orden)
{
    ViewBag.cal = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Orden) ? "cod_asc" : "";

    var modelo = (from c in db.TB_Profesionales
                  where c.IDSERVICIO == id 
                  select new 
                         {
                             IDUSUARIO = c.IDUSUARIO,
                             NOMBRE = c.NOMBRE,
                             APELLIDO = c.APELLIDO,
                             SEXO = c.SEXO,
                             DISTRITO = c.DISTRITO,
                             DESCRIPCIÓN = c.DESCRIPCIÓN,
                             PROMEDIOCAL = c.PROMEDIOCAL
                         })
                 .ToList()
                 .Select(x => new TB_Profesionales()
                                  {
                                      IDUSUARIO = x.IDUSUARIO,
                                      NOMBRE = x.NOMBRE,
                                      APELLIDO = x.APELLIDO,
                                      SEXO = x.SEXO,
                                      DISTRITO = x.DISTRITO,
                                      DESCRIPCIÓN = x.DESCRIPCIÓN,
                                      PROMEDIOCAL = x.PROMEDIOCAL
                                  });

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CadenaBusqueda))
    {
        modelo = modelo.Where(s => s.DISTRITO.ToUpper().Contains(CadenaBusqueda.ToUpper()));
        return View(modelo.ToList());
    }

    switch (Orden)
    {
        case "cod_asc":
            modelo = modelo.OrderByDescending(s => s.PROMEDIOCAL);
            break;
    }

    return View(modelo.ToList());
}
```

**VIEW:**

@Html.TextBox("CadenaBusqueda", null, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Ingrese distrito" })

@Html.ActionLink("Cod", "ListarProfxServicio", new {Orden = ViewBag.cal })
a

Comment: Why do you run the `Select` twice? First you get all the properties to an anonymous type, then select all the same properties to a `new TB_Profesionales()`?

Answer (score 0):

In your code the ordering doesn't run if a search term is given.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CadenaBusqueda))
{
    modelo = modelo.Where(s => s.DISTRITO.ToUpper().Contains(CadenaBusqueda.ToUpper()));
    return View(modelo.ToList());    <-- This here goes to the view, and nothing after it is run.
}

switch (Orden)
{
    case "cod_asc":
        modelo = modelo.OrderByDescending(s => s.PROMEDIOCAL);
        break;
}

return View(modelo.ToList());
```

Instead, you should only `return` a value when everything needed is done. Easiest solution would be to remove the `return View(modelo.ToList());` from the `if`-block, like this:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CadenaBusqueda))
{
    modelo = modelo.Where(s => s.DISTRITO.ToUpper().Contains(CadenaBusqueda.ToUpper())).ToList();
}

switch (Orden)
{
    case "cod_asc":
        modelo = modelo.OrderByDescending(s => s.PROMEDIOCAL).ToList();
        break;
}

return View(modelo);
```

You only need to call `return` once, the variable `modelo` is modified conditionally, meaning changed if needed, but always returned.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it works exactly the same. It doesn't respect filtering and when I want to sort the column it lists everything again

Comment: Try executing the query after filtering, then sort the filtered collection, ie add `ToList()` method to the `if`-block. I've updated the snippet in the answer.

Comment: I just applied your updated suggestion and I haven't been successful :( everything is relisted when sorting the column